# Connection between android device and bluetooth headsets programatically

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

How can i make an app in android that can provide connection between the android device and the bluetooth speakers.

Comment: You may need to do research yourself, then post question if you face any issues

Answer (score 0):

How to pair:

```
   private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
            try {
                Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
                method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

How to Unpair:

```
 private void unpairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
            try {
                Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("removeBond", (Class[]) null);
                method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

The receiver to catch the pairing process:

```
 private final BroadcastReceiver mPairReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();

                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
                     final int state        = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);
                     final int prevState    = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);

                     if (state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED && prevState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                         showToast("Paired");
                     } else if (state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE && prevState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED){
                         showToast("Unpaired");
                     }

                }
            }
        };
```

Register receiver:

```
IntentFilter intent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(mPairReceiver, intent);
```

Comment: does it gets connect with audio devices??